# in Asp.net vb how do you iterate though a set of panels withing another containing panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, panel, loops

I want to be able to iterate through a set of panels and set their background color but ive used the code:-

```
For Each ctrl In status.Controls
            If ctrl Is Panel Then
                ctrl.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        Next
```

The error i get is "Panel is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

status control is another panel with houses the smaller panels, makes it easier to hide the lot when needed.

how can I do this without resorting to if thens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code a little:

```
For Each ctrl In status.Controls 
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Panel Then 
        ctrl.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: cheers, was wondering if it was possible, the strict option on was limiting my use of the control properties as well.